# Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in when making an array from $_post from checkbox being cheked

Tags: php

I have been struggling for days on this issue.  I have simplified my code to try and get the root issue. I am checking boxes on another page and returning post value into this one.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['checkbox'])){



            $selected=array($_POST['checkbox']);
                $count = count($_POST['checkbox']);
           echo "There are ".$count." checkboxe(s) are checked<br>";                  


            for ($q=0;$q<$count;$q++){


                print_r($selected[$q]);

}
}

?>
```

I am getting this error:

```
  There are 5 checkboxe(s) are checked
 501
 Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 3 in F:\HTML\write to HTML table.php      on line 19

 Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 4 in F:\HTML\write to HTML table.php on line 19
 505
 Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 3 in F:\HTML\write to HTML table.php on line 19

 Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 4 in F:\HTML\write to HTML table.php on line 19
 516
 Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 3 in F:\HTML\write to HTML table.php on line 19

 Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 4 in F:\HTML\write to HTML table.php on line 19
 518
 Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 3 in F:\HTML\write to HTML table.php on line 19

 Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 4 in F:\HTML\write to HTML table.php on line 19
 529
 Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 3 in F:\HTML\write to HTML table.php on line 19

 Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 4 in F:\HTML\write to HTML table.php on line 19
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting `$_POST['checkbox']` into another array, you need to parse It or you need to assign well `$selected` variable

try to change this:

```
print_r($selected[$q]);
```

to this:

```
print_r($_POST['checkbox'][$q]);
```

or you need to change how you set `$selected` editing into this:

```
$selected = $_POST['checkbox'];
```